# making an asynchronous call to database without waiting for promise to resolve

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I'm using AWS-Lambda and all of my queries are update statement. I want to send an async call to database and then end the AWS-lambda without waiting for the promise to resolve. I want to know if that's possible or not. would also love insights on how the connection to db is establish and persists.

**results in connection terminated error**

```
--inside aws lambda
client = new Client("conectinString") // rds-proxy connection
client.connect()
client.query('call the store procedure')
client.end()
```

**This works but is creating too many connections to proxy server**

```
--inside aws lambda

client = new Client("conectinString") // rds-proxy connection
client.connect()
client.query('call the store procedure')
```

**I'm using rds-proxy, is there a way to terminate previous connection or reuse the connection if the connection request is trying to connect to same instance.**

this is my first post, please let me know if I have missed something to mention.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [pools](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#pooling-connections) rather than create more connections.

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var pool  = mysql.createPool(...);

pool.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
  if (err) throw err; // not connected!

  // Use the connection
  connection.query('SELECT something FROM sometable', function (error, results, fields) {
    // When done with the connection, release it.
    connection.release();

    // Handle error after the release.
    if (error) throw error;

    // Don't use the connection here, it has been returned to the pool.
  });
});
```

Comment: But, everytime the connection database is different, we are using multiple instance and runing same store procedure in each of them.